# How to add an aggregate result from a SOQL query inside a map? Shows error- Unexpected token '['

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, map, aggregateresult

I am trying to create a map of Opportunity ids and a count of its Opportunity Line Items.

```
Map<Id,Integer> opptyIdLineCount = new Map<Id, Integer>();
AggregateResult[] aggOpptyIdLineCount = [SELECT OpportunityId, COUNT(Id)count
                                         FROM OpportunityLineItem
                                         GROUP BY OpportunityId];
for(AggregateResult agg : aggOpptyIdLineCount){
    opptyIdLineCount.put((Id)agg.get('Id'), Integer(agg.get('count')));
}
```

Shows error-

> Unexpected token '['

when I try to run this snippet in Anonymous Window. I've tried the using `List<AggregateResult>` as well but shows

> Unexpected token `'<'`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`count` is a reserved word and cannot be your alias. Change it to somenthing like `recordCount` and your query will work

Example:

```
AggregateResult[] aggOpptyIdLineCount = [SELECT OpportunityId, COUNT(Id) recordCount
                                         FROM OpportunityLineItem
                                         GROUP BY OpportunityId];
```

Comment: You'll also need the right key for the OpportunityId. Either add an alias (that's not a reserved word like 'Id') or use the full field name in your `agg.get()`

Comment: Thank you Sebastian and Thomas. The snippet worked after I made the changes:
    AggregateResult[] aggOpptyIdLineCount = [SELECT  OpportunityId,
                                                       COUNT(Id)recordCount
                                           FROM   OpportunityLineItem
                                          GROUP BY OpportunityId];
    for(AggregateResult agg : aggOpptyIdLineCount){
        opptyIdLineCount.put((Id)agg.get('OpportunityId'), (Integer) 
   (agg.get('recordCount')));
    }